# knockout linked select options

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm starting wit knockout and I'm trying to create a linked `<select>` much like
the usual country selectors out there, where when you select a country the states list is updated to show only the states of the selected country.

I managed to make it work almost as I'd like, but a problem remains.

My k.o.:

```
var AppViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;


        self.categories = [{ Name: "A", Sub: [{ Name: "A1" }, { Name: "A2" }] }, { Name: "B", Sub: [] }];


        // the one we are working with.
        self.currentCategory = ko.observable(self.categories[0]);
        self.currentSubcategory = ko.observable();

    };
```

My html:

```
<select data-bind="options: categories,
optionsText: 'Name',
value: currentCategory"></select>

<select data-bind="options: currentCategory().Subcategories,
optionsText: 'Name',
value: currentSubcategory"></select>
```

This works well if all `categories` have the `Sub` property populated.
However, if `Sub` if empty, like in `B` from the example above, then when I select it, I get an error in the console: `Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined`, because `currentCategory().Subcategories` will be an empty array for `B`.

My question is: how do I go about solving this? I expected knockout to not try to render anything because `B.Subcategories` is empty... It is weird: why doesn't it just render an empty ?

**Similar problem:**

If I want to user `optionsCaption`, then my value can't be a complex object, from what I understood, because the caption is a string.

So if I modify the html:

```
<select data-bind="options: categories,
optionsCaption: 'Select a category',
optionsText: 'Name',
optionsValue: 'Id',
value: currentCategory"></select>

<select data-bind="options: categories[currentCategory].Subcategories,
optionsCaption: 'Select a subcategory',
optionsText: 'Name',
optionsValue: 'Id',
value: currentSubcategory"></select>
```

I will run into the same problem, because when the `optionsCaption` is selected, `currentCategory` is not a valid index for the `categories` array.

Here is a fiddle with my code almost working, except when I select B the second list is not updated to empty until I select it manually.
https://jsfiddle.net/byxL373j/1/

```js
        var AppViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;


            self.categories = [{ Name: "A", Sub: [{ Name: "A1" }, { Name: "A2" }] }, { Name: "B", Sub: [] }];


            // the one we are working with.
            self.currentCategory = ko.observable();
            self.currentSubcategory = ko.observable();

        };

        var viewModel = new AppViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <select data-bind="options: categories,
    optionsText: 'Name',
    value: currentCategory"></select>

    <select data-bind="foreach: currentCategory().Sub,
    value: currentSubcategory">

        <option data-bind="text: Name, value: $data"></option>

    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first issue, you don't have `currentCategory().Subcategories` defined anywhere, it will then always show an error. Use `currentCategory().Sub` instead. Then you can use visible binding on second select:

```js
        var AppViewModel = function() {
          var self = this;


          self.categories = [{
            Name: "A",
            Sub: [{
              Name: "A1"
            }, {
              Name: "A2"
            }]
          }, {
            Name: "B",
            Sub: []
          }];


          // the one we are working with.
          self.currentCategory = ko.observable();
          self.currentSubcategory = ko.observable();

        };

        var viewModel = new AppViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: categories,
    optionsText: 'Name',
    value: currentCategory"></select>


<select data-bind="options: currentCategory().Sub,
    value: currentSubcategory,
    optionsText: 'Name',
    visible: currentCategory().Sub.length > 0">
</select>
```

and if you want to display category helper text you can do the following. Notice the virtual `if` binding - it will not even try to look at the code inside the comment unless your category is first selected. This is what's making it not to break/give console error.

```js
var AppViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;


  self.categories = [{
    Name: "A",
    Sub: [{
      Name: "A1"
    }, {
      Name: "A2"
    }]
  }, {
    Name: "B",
    Sub: []
  }];


  // the one we are working with.
  self.currentCategory = ko.observable();
  self.currentSubcategory = ko.observable();

};

var viewModel = new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}
hr {
  margin: 22px 0;
}
hr + p {
  margin-bottom: 11px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: categories,
    optionsCaption: 'Select a category',
    optionsText: 'Name',
    value: currentCategory"></select>

<!-- ko if: currentCategory -->
<select data-bind="options: currentCategory().Sub,
    value: currentSubcategory,
    optionsCaption: 'Select a subcategory',
    optionsText: 'Name',
    visible: currentCategory().Sub.length > 0">
</select>
<!-- /ko -->


<hr>
<p>debug:</p>
<p>Selected category:
  <span data-bind="if: currentCategory"> 
    <span data-bind="text: currentCategory().Name"></span></span>
  <span data-bind="if: !currentCategory()">none</span>
</p>
<p>Selected subcategory:
  <span data-bind="if: currentSubcategory"> 
    <span data-bind="text: currentSubcategory().Name"></span></span>
  <span data-bind="if: !currentSubcategory()">none</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Hey @kasperoo, thanks for the reply. About the Subcategory not being defined, it was just a typo, if you check my fiddle and the snippet you will see that the code is correct. I used the if yesterday just like you said, but I don't really like this solution because I might want to show  the second select even tho it is empty. I did not know the visible binding, very cool.
Run my snippet, and see that the second select is not updated to empty when you select B.